# Google Analytics implementation problems

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I am trying to implement GA to track traffic to a Medium page. First of all I don´t know and I couldn´t found if this is trackable at all since I don´t really "own" this url.

I have tried the two ways: by the global website tag (gtag.js) and by Google Tag Manager.

- On global website tag I am not really sure I could implement it since I tried to modify the source code of the page but it didn´t save.
- On GTM y created a tag (GA4 configuration) with "all pages" activators and it shouldn´t be much more trouble.

The thing here is than when I open the Tag Assitant Legacy it just finds one tag [GTA tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Owc.png) and it does with a UA identity, even though I always tried to configure the two options above with the new identities G-XXXXXXXXXX.

All in all, I have three questions here:

1. Is it possible to modify the source code of a webpage? If it is, is it specifically with Medium? If yes, how?
2. Why does GTA shows just one tag if I tried to configure two?
3. Why the configured task shows a legacy identity (UA-xxxxxx) if I always used the new one (G-xxxxx).

Just to finish and give the complete picture here, when I try the Tag Assistant, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoZtb.png) is what appears. Here I can only recognize the first code (which is the same than the GTA one). Moreover, it sometimes sends the "can´t connect to the website message" once in a while.

So much problems, so many questions; if anyone can help I would really appreciate that.
Thanks so much!

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to track exits from a website you control out to a Medium URL?

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
No, I am trying to know how many visits this Medium URL has, but I don´t know if it can be done since it "is not my domain"

Comment: Unfortunately, since you don't control the domain, you're limited to only those tools that Medium allows you access to, which might not include Google Analytics.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I was thinking something like that... thank you all!